# Combination of group's math php function

Tags: php, math, combinations

Looking for a function in php for possible element combinations of unknown number of groups like
{x, y...z}...{x,y...z}
example:

```
A:{1,2,3,4},B:{5,6},C:{a,b,c}
```

Result:

```
ABC
15a
15b
15c
16a
16b
16c
25a
25b
25c
26a
26b
26c
35a
35b
.
.
.
46c
```

I just need something like this but this is not working

```
$array = array( 'A' => array(1, 2, 3, 4), 'B' => array(5, 6). 'C' => array('a', 'b', 'c'))

function makeCombinations($array){ 
    foreach($array as $value){makeCombinations($array)
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you already tried?

Comment: was A,B,C  are arrays ?

Comment: You should have given a try atleast, 3 arrays iterate over each of them and print the value as shown by Krishna below

Comment: I am tying to code a function that adds up a foreach loop for each array. I ll make an edit in a sec

Comment: you have syntax error her `array(5, 6).` please change `.` to `,`. Also while calling function again inside a function you should call using `$value` and not `$array`.

Comment: i think it is not possible to make a recursive function, as all the arrays that is needed for o/p is at same level.If your array structure looks like this and no more complication then you my answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

Assuming A ,B , C were arrays

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$b = array(5,6);
$c = array("a","b","c");

foreach($a as $values)
    foreach($b as $values2)
        foreach($c as $values3)
            echo $values."".$values2."".$values3."\n";
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/71pvd)

Comment: I am tying to code a function that adds up a foreach loop for each array. I ll make an edit in a sec